# Zlib linker error on vs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, zlib

I have a zlib linker error. Spent several hours to try and solve the problem but nothing so far. Zlib was built using vs2010, win32 release. My project is using the same.

Error extract:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflateEnd@4 referenced in function
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflate@8 referenced in function
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflateInit_@16 referenced in function
```

Including the zlib.h in the file like this:

```
#ifdef WIN32
# define ZLIB_WINAPI
#endif
#include "zlib.h"
```

Project settings:

**Linker->General->Additional Library Dependencies**: C:\somepath\zlib

**Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies**: zlibstatic.lib

Linker verbose output (not full, just for zlib):

```
Searching C:\somepath\zlib\zlibstatic.lib:
Searching C:\somepath\zlib\zlibstatic.lib:
```

Two direct hits yet it doesn't do anything..

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424549/unresolved-externals-despite-linking-in-zlib-lib) question but I do not think I have that problem because:

1. I did not use contrib solution, I generated one with **cmake -G
   "Visual Studio 10"**
2. I have ZLIB_WINAPI defined before include as
   comment to top answer suggests.

It is actually an open source project so if someone can try and reproduce the problem:

1. Clone https://github.com/d1zzy/pvpgn.git
2. Add zlib libraries and include files to pvpgn/pvpgn/zlib (or anywhere else, just edit cmake/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake with your custom zlib path)
3. Run cmake -G "Visual Studio 10", open the solution and try to build project "bnetd"

Comment: I'm not a Windows user but on UNIXes I would verify that the target for the searched library is the same as the one need, in particular that they use the same number of bits.

Comment: have you checked if these symbols "deflateEnd" exist by inspecting the contents of zlibstatic.lib?

Comment: see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/088ce0f9-b556-45b9-b0b5-d1104343d50e/zlib-and-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol

Comment: @goldcode: I opened the lib with a text editor and there seem to be references all over the place. Should be ok.
I saw that MSDN link while googling around but it can't be the problem in my case. As I said above, I build zlib with win32 target and I am building my project with win32 target. There is no 64bit anywhere.

Comment: try adding #pragma comment(lib, "zlibstatic.lib") in the file where you include zlib.h

Comment: Still nothing. Since it's an open source project I edited the first post with steps to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds to me like a mismatch of the symbols in your zlibstatic.lib vs. what you are looking for
in through your include.
Please try:

1. Open a command prompt on windows
2. change to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin
   (or your VS install directory)
3. execute vcvars32.bat
4. dumpbin zlibstatic.lib /symbols > symbols.txt
5. check the symbols.txt for deflateEnd, deflate, and deflateInit

my output looks like this:

```
026 00000AA0 SECT4  notype ()    External     | _deflate
011 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | _deflateInit_
02C 00001AC0 SECT4  notype ()    External     | _deflateEnd
```

my guess is that your dumpbin output looks the same as mine.
Now compare my output to your missing symbols

Your missing symbols: _deflateEnd@4, _deflate@8 and *deflateInit*@16

The @X postfix gives me a hint that your code is looking for the function in standard calling conventions
but your library is built using the c calling convention.

```
void _cdecl deflate();      // ==> _deflate
void __stdcall deflate();   // ==> _deflate@8
```

Try including "zlib.h" without ZLIB_WINAPI defined but ultimatily dumping the symbols with dumpbin should give you a clue.

Another possiblity - you may have compiled zlibstatic.lib with #define Z_PREFIX

Comment: Here is pastebin of the symbol dump: http://pastebin.com/fjf3jV3V . I built zlib the following way: download zlib 1.28, cmake -G "Visual Studio 10", build zlibstatic project with Release win32. Any problem with this? Anyway, removing ZLIB_WINAPI worked! Any idea why? I've read this http://www.zlib.net/DLL_FAQ.txt and the FAQ suggests that ZLIB_WINAPI is only meant to be used with dll. I will try to build with ZLIB_WINAPI and a dll to see what happens

Comment: As I guessed your dumpbin shows:


527 : 01C 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | _deflate



You are building your library with _cdecl convention.
Now you have to include with the same convention.
The library and header must use the same convention.
Either both _cdecl or both __stdcall.

Please change one or the other.

First try including without #define ZLIB_WINAPI.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in Visual Studio 2015, I assume the .lib has been compiled using the "ZBLI_WINAPI" preprocessor definition, As Markus Schumann mentioned.

Right clicking on the project > properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor, adding "ZBLI_WINAPI" to "Preprocessor Definitions" and rebuilding solved it for me.